# calculating closed issues within an open or created period SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to get a report out of our help desk that will give me by user the number of opened and closed issues in a given week.

The week is determined by the date that the query was submitted.

Defining the number of opened issues is easy as it's just a count on the number of ID's in that week.

The problem is that because I'm doing this by the open date, I can't figure out how to work out the number of issues that have been closed in the same period.

Example of the data would be:

```
    ID  | Open Date  | Closed Date
    1   | 01/01/2013 | 01/01/2013
    2   | 05/01/2013 | 05/01/2013
    3   | 05/01/2013 | 10/01/2013
    4   | 10/01/2013 | 10/01/2013
    5   | 15/01/2013 |
```

In this example I would want the report to say:

```
  Week | Opened | Closed
  1    | 3      | 2
  2    | 1      | 2
  3    | 1      | 0
```

I'm sure that this is a common question but I've searched all day and just can't find a solution.

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2.

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: What starting and end days determine the week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATEPART` to obtain the week number of the year:

**UPDATED**

As Conrad Fix said on a comment, you should add the year to your result set:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(A.[Year],B.[Year]) [Year],
        ISNULL(A.[Week],B.[Week]) [Week],
        ISNULL(A.Opened,0) Opened,
        ISNULL(B.Closed,0) Closed
FROM (  SELECT  YEAR(OpenDate) [Year],
                DATEPART(WEEK,OpenDate) [Week],
                COUNT(*) Opened
        FROM YourTable 
        WHERE [OpenDate] IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY YEAR(OpenDate), DATEPART(WEEK,OpenDate)) A
FULL JOIN ( SELECT  YEAR(ClosedDate) [Year],
                    DATEPART(WEEK,ClosedDate) [Week],
                    COUNT(*) Closed
            FROM YourTable 
            WHERE [ClosedDate] IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY YEAR(ClosedDate), DATEPART(WEEK,ClosedDate)) B
    ON A.[Year] = B.[Year] AND A.[Week] = B.[Week]
ORDER BY [Year], [Week]
```

Results:

```
╔══════╦══════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Year ║ Week ║ Opened ║ Closed ║
╠══════╬══════╬════════╬════════╣
║ 2013 ║    1 ║      3 ║      2 ║
║ 2013 ║    2 ║      1 ║      2 ║
║ 2013 ║    3 ║      1 ║      0 ║
╚══════╩══════╩════════╩════════╝
```

And [**here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d619/2) with a demo.

Comment: The OP should probably want to add the year in there

Comment: @ConradFrix Absolutely, fixed my answer. Thanks

Comment: This worked like an absolute charm!! I was even able to adapt it to add in the timer so I could work out average response times etc! Thank you so much for your help!!!